# Как уменьшить отступы справа и слева на странице (ASP.NET CORE 3.1 MVC)

Tags: c#, bootstrap, asp.net-core-mvc, отступы, core

возможно глупый вопрос, но хотел бы узнать, как можно уменьшить отступ справ и слева от основного тела сайта (Скрин приложил).

Суть в том, что нужно отобразить таблицу, она будет большая, дополнительное место очень важно. Web-приложение создано шаблоном на ASP.NET Core 3.1, отступы по стандарту, ничего в этом плане не менялось.

[image: Отступы]

Comment: У вас предустановлен бутстрап, который позволяет делать страницы адаптивными, и имеет условную размерность 12 по ширине. Чтобы корректно ответить на ваш вопрос выложите код этой страницы, но не скриншотом, а полным кодом. Если интереcно, то вот в этом [репозитории](https://github.com/AndyBrizhak/Rocky-Part-2/commit/f7a0e7f6372e0ec757536986b4499b6a6b61eeca) код для ASP.NET Core MVC под .NET 5, в том числе и настройка ширины и внешнего вида таблиц, с использованием стилизации за [datatables.net](https://datatables.net/).

Comment: Там максимально пустая страница, только teg <div> и <table> в через который создана таблица, больше ничего нету, а более простым способом нельзя изменить размерность с 12 на 4 например?

Comment: Первое, выложите код страницы, не ленитесь, если хотите получить адекватную помощь. Второе изучите документацию [бутстрап](https://bootstrap-5.ru/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Достаточно поменять в файле Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml

```
<div class="container">
```

на

```
<div class="container-fluid">
```

Документация: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/containers/